# Getting a background image to stretch vertically

Tags: html, css

I created a webpage with some simple CSS with a striped image (62px width, and 32px height) and I want it to repeat vertically all the way down to the bottom of the page. My issue is that it stops at the end of the content, such as if I put "Test," it will be very small. If I have an entire essay, it will repeat with it - but not much if the page doesn't scroll.

Image: http://avaworld.net/images/bordLeft-blue.png

Website - http://www.avaworld.net/

`#blueWrap {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #131313;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}`

`#blueRight {
    padding-right: 62px;
    background: url(http://avaworld.net/images/bordRight-blue.png) top right repeat-y;
}`

`#blueLeft {
    padding-left: 62px;
    background: url(http://avaworld.net/images/bordLeft-blue.png) top left repeat-y;
}`

```
<div id="blueWrap">
    <div id="blueRight">
      <div id="blueLeft">
        Test
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply this to your css

```
body, #blueWrap, #blueRight, #blueLeft{height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `body, #blueWrap, #blueRight, #blueLeft{height:100%;}` is that when you have a lot of content, the `blueRight` and `blueLeft` elements will not follow the page while scrolling.

For the `blueRight` and `blueLeft` attributes, in their css try adding: `position: fixed; height: 100%;`

`position: fixed;` means that the `div` will stay on that exact position even when scrolled.

`height: 100%;` is to make the height 100%.